# Visual Basic Query

Tags: sql, vb.net

Im not the best at VB Or SQL & need a little help with this.
Was just curious as to how to query this.

TABLES:
Game Table Includes Game ID And a few other things
Review Table includes Review ID And a few other things
Reference Table contains Game ID Linking to a Review ID Both are primary keys of their own tables.

QUERY:
I need a query that would Select * from the Review table where the Game ID Matches a label I have. ( lblGameID.Text )
I know this is wrong but I have this at the moment:

```
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Review WHERE GameID = '" & lblGameID.Text & "' "
```

Comment: Well, for starters that's "wrong" because it's wide open to SQL injection attacks.  You should use query parameters instead of executing user input as code.  Aside from that, what exactly isn't working?  What happens when you run your code?  Is there a compiler error?  A runtime exception?  How does it fail?

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a JOIN.  `Reference` is how you get a Game with a ReviewID, or get a Review using a GameID

Comment: seems odd that you'd be getting the value to query from a label assuming lbl means label.  Additionally is GameID numeric?  If so then you shoudlnt' have it wrapped in tics.  Additionally I do not see where you execute this query and have a recordset to work with.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That technique of string-compositing a query is generally a bad idea, but if you have complete control of what goes into the query as lblGameID.Text, then it's OK. Usually better is to create a stored procedure that runs this query:

```
select * 
from review r
    join reference ref on r.reviewID = ref.reviewID
where ref.gameID = @gameID
```

and then call it from VB, throwing the returned data into a DataTable. Something like:

```
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("connectionString")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("exec reviewDataGet @gameID", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gameID", lblGameID.Text)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    da.Fill(dt)
```